# How significant is performance difference between "DATE(mydate) = CURDATE()" vs "mydate = CURDATE()"?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

```
DATE(mydate) = CURDATE()
```

vs

```
mydate = CURDATE()
```

I have a pretty performance sensitive situation with tens of millions of rows, and I'm wondering if storing only date in `datetime` field and time in a separate columns, just to have a simple `mydate = CURDATE()` comparison when looking up records by days, would be significantly faster than merging both information in `datetime` field and using `DATE(mydate) = CURDATE()`.

(yes, I cannot use "date" data type, because of the abstraction layer between me and the database)

Would there be a significant difference or is there a better way to get all records from the given day when using `datetime` field?

Comment: 1st variant cannot use index.

Comment: `mydate >= CURDATE() AND mydate < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` (edit depending on your DBMS and how it implements date arithmetic). Works for date / datetime / timestamp datatypes.

Comment: Sorry guys I tagged this question with `mysql` I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just asked

> How significant is performance difference between “DATE(mydate) = CURDATE()” vs “mydate = CURDATE()”?

My Answer

> Very Gigantic Difference

When you use

```
DATE(mydate) = CURDATE()
```

The Query Optimizer will suggest a full table scan even if the column is indexed. Why ? The Query Optimizer is obligated to see the need to call the `DATE()` function against `mydate` in every row, thus eliminating the idea of using the index. Additionally, using `FORCE INDEX` will simply get you nowhere.

If `mydate` is `datetime` and is indexed, you could then change the query to

```
mydate >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND) AND
mydate <  (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 86400 SECOND)
```

or

```
mydate >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND) AND
mydate <  (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
```

so you are comparing `datetime` to `datetime` and isolating just today. In this instance, an index on `mydate` will be used.

You do not want to split the date and time into spearate columns as that will cause comparisons of datetime ranges across multiple dates and times very difficult to express in SQL.

Comment: Won't it be significantly slower to have `>=` and `<` instead of `=` though? The thing is, that my data make sense only on the "day" scale, so I'm not really concerned about querying across multiple days, as I simply do not expect it to ever happen.

Comment: If `mydate` is indexed, it will traverse the index first. This will be faster. If `mydate` is not indexed, then there will be no improvement.

Comment: I@RolandoMySQLDBA - I think that ` + INTERVAL 0 SECOND` is unnecessary in all the places you used it.  Also, `DATETIMEs` and `DATE` can be compared, with the understanding that a `DATE` is implicitly midnight that morning.